# Could a Cessna Caravan be outfitted with Wi-Fi?

Tags: aircraft-design, commercial-aviation, antenna

From what I understand, both ATG and satellite Wi-Fi require substantially large antennas to send and receive signals in large commercial airplanes.

Could a system like this be outfitted on a Cessna Caravan, and how does the fact that the airplane flies lower and slower than larger jets influence that?

Comment: Ask Starlink?  The terrrstrial antennas are not that big...

Comment: Most Caravans won't venture above 10000ft or far from land most of the time, so just use your mobile phone.

Comment: WiFi is nothing more than a set of protocols for transmitting Ethernet data packets without wires. Your cell phone can create a WiFi hotspot, so if your cell phone has power, then creating one in a Cessna Caravan or any other aircraft is trivial. If you have 120v power available, any WiFi enabled router can be plugged in, and the network configured on it will start working. Are you looking for broader Internet access? That would take some sort of external signal processing, but the same cell phone shouldn't have a problem talking to terrestrial towers at low altitudes & slow speeds.

Comment: @CatchAsCatchCan There are more limitations to this that there may seem.  You'll typically get good LTE or 5G performance *very* close to the ground.  But above a few hundred feet AGL the problems compound.  Your phone will be "seen" by many towers simultaneously and you will seem essentially equidistant to quite a few of them.  Both your phone and the system will often recognize this and say "not so fast, sea biscuit."  This is why you'll often see multiple bars of data service and a 4G or 5G indicator, but still have no data connection.

Comment: @MartinJames The recommended Starlink antenna for mobile applications is a 20" x 20" flat panel, that has to be external to the fuselage, so it becomes a significant approvals problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bendix King offers a TSO'd Inmarsat internet transceiver for the Caravan called an AeroWave 100, so the shortest answer is "yes."  It's not inexpensive, you're looking at an installation north of 30 to 40,000 USD before WiFi.  And you are correct, the antenna is the hardest part to deal with.

Comment: What about Iridium GO!? https://www.iridium.com/products/iridium-go/

Comment: @Someone Could be doable, but in most metal aircraft you'll *really* want that antenna outside the fuselage and are like staring down TSO/STC approval.

Comment: @Someone Iridium GO! provides short burst data and voice calls. It essentially does text messages, but no true internet access, like OP is likely imagining. They make a suction cup windshield antenna designed for aviation applications.

Comment: @user71659 oh, okay. I thought it gave Internet access.